# Methods for tracking processing time for long running ADD INDEX call in MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-8.0

I've set off index creation on a very large table in MySQL and while I expected it to take a long time, I'm 5 days in and wondering if there's any way to debug potential issues or simply let it run.  I don't have a precise row count but to estimate, it's in the 100s of billions of rows and the table is ~400GB on disk.  Neither memory or CPU usage appears to be overly taxed (mem ~8GB (out of 16GB total)).

The call I made from within MySQL is as follows:

```
alter table prices add index(dataDate, ticker, expDate, type), add index(s
ymbol), algorithm=inplace, lock=none;
```

Running `show processlist` from within a different MySQL instance shows the call with State 'altering table' so the call doesn't appear blocked.  Anything else I can check to gauge progress?

For reference I'm working with MySQL 8 and within Ubuntu 18.04.

**Edit:**  Indexes eventually completed, took a little over 9 days.

Comment: Eh?  100 billion rows will not fit in 400GB of disk space!  Which number is wrong?

Comment: What query do you think that index will help?  Usually starting with a "date" is counter-productive.

Comment: @RickJames, counterproductive even when `dataDate` will be used within where clauses?

Comment: `WHERE x=1 AND date BETWEEN...` works better with `INDEX(x, date)` than having the index in the opposite order.  Even if `x` is just true/false.

Comment: And...  Here is my "proof":  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239658/higher-cardinality-column-first-in-an-index-when-involving-a-range

Comment: @RickJames, this is interesting, thanks for adding.  By that logic, the best approach would have been for my index to look like (ticker, type, dataDate, expDate), yes?  Identifying columns first (and the higher cardinality between the two first) and range columns last.

Comment: I claim that swapping the first two won't matter.  And (independently) that only one "range" will be used.  OTOH, if the 4 columns are all that occur in the SELECT, then the 4-column index is beneficial, but due to being "covering".  Feel free to ask another Question with a specific SELECT (and EXPLAIN) and a specific CREATE TABLE.  I will eagerly try to prove my point.  (If I fail, I will try to find a reason for my failure.)